# Deleted folder is still visible and one folder is unavailable

Tags: windows-10

I have these 2 folders in my Downloads directory, the problem with both is that they are not being deleted.
The first one let's say folder A, when I try to delete it says the directory does not exist with an error code 0x80004005.
And the second folder (say B), when I delete it there is no pop-up message for that but still, the folder is visible.

Added details from comment by OP

482537471 KB total disk space. 262760260 KB in 336242 files. 188212 KB in 74979 indexes. 0 KB in bad sectors. 1258115 KB in use by the system. 65536 KB occupied by the log file. 218330884 KB available on disk. 4096 bytes in each allocation unit. 120634367 total allocation units on disk. 54582721 allocation units available on disk. Total duration: 29.80 seconds (29808 ms). I got this after running the check disk command

Comment: The error code `0x8000405` is wrong. Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1654674/edit) your question to correct. As a first test, run `chkdsk C:` to verify the disk.

Comment: 482537471 KB total disk space.
 262760260 KB in 336242 files.
    188212 KB in 74979 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
   1258115 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 218330884 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 120634367 total allocation units on disk.
  54582721 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 29.80 seconds (29808 ms).

I got this after running the check disk command

Comment: You should put such information inside your question - it's not very clear this way. And what is the real error code?

Comment: Error 0x80004005: Unspecified Error

Comment: Are these folders located inside a network share?

Comment: No, on my hard disk in the Downloads directory.

Comment: Use CMD, position to the folder (`cd path`) and enter `dir /x` for the two folders. Use the short-names of the folders with the rmdir command: `rmdir /s /q xxxxx~1.yyy`. If it doesn't work, repeat in a CMD run as Administrator.

Comment: Already tried this even running CMD as an administrator still the two folders are visible.
After running the rmdir command it shows that "the system cannot find the file path specified".

Comment: I suggest using a Linux Live USB to remove the two folders.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do that. Can you link me to a guide or tutorial?

Comment: This will get you started, although you will need to divert from it in order to delete the folder: [How to Retrieve Windows Files Using a Linux Live CD](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-retrieve-windows-files-using-a-linux-live-cd/).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ab7WTFFnYl0
I watched this video and this worked for me.

Comment: Isn't it the same as my above suggestion?

Comment: I dunno what's the difference but this is definitely less tedious.